# How do I create/edit a Manifest file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, manifest

I have this code from a coworker (probably got it from the web somewhere) but he's out on vacation and I need to add this to the manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
    xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
    xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication" />
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" 
        uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

I am relatively new to this so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force C# App to run as administrator on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 and possibly in future versions you can add the manifest file to your project.

Right click on your *project file* on the *Solution Explorer*, select `Add`, then `New item` (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). There you can find `Application Manifest File`.

The file name is **app.manifest**. [image: app manifest icon]

If this item doesn't exist then your project type is not conform with a manifest file, e.g. web application.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to create the file properly.

Comment: Ibram's instructions also apply to Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: and Visual Studio 2013 as well.

Comment: Cocoa, It creates a default manifest. You are able to change things in it (such as "program requires admin execution level") but you are free to keep it default

Comment: It may be worth mentioning, that using the default manifest which is created by this method and which contains the node "<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication" /> as above makes at least not much sense and is confusing at least. I am not sure, if this could be even the source of further problems as the assemblyname and version in the manifest could be false and not taken from 'AssemblyInfo.cs' ? I use only the parts which make sense of that "template". Especially I am adding the operating system keys, e.g. for Win 10 which even VS 2013 doesn't know yet.

Comment: I wonder where the `Application Manifest File` template comes from, because there is nothing with that name (or even with `manifest` in the name) when I followed those instructions and looked at _every_ branch of the new item type tree. I'm using VS2019 16.11.5 (and started with v16.0.0, followed by every update) but I only install what I need to develop native C/C++ projects for Windows. I must need to install something I don't need to get this thing that I kinda need...  Sigh.

Comment: @SteveValliere The manifest file could only be used in the .NET framework. I think you can't use it in a native C/C++ project.

Answer (score 41):

As ibram stated, add the manifest thru solution explorer:

[image]

This creates a default manifest.  Now, edit the manifest.

- Update the assemblyIdentity name as your application.
- Ask users to trust your application

[image]

- Add supported OS

[image]

Comment: The `<applicationRequestMinimum>` node does not come up be default? Is it something you have added for a reason? I am using VS2015

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way to create a manifest is:

1. Project Properties -> Security -> Click "enable ClickOnce security settings"
   (it will generate default manifest in your project Properties)
2. then Click it again in order to uncheck that Checkbox
3. open your `app.maifest` and edit it as you wish.

[image: Manifest location preview]

Comment: This appears to no longer be creating a manifest (VS 2019, .Net 4.7, WinForms application).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Tested right now with VS 2019, .NET 4.7.2 and Winforms(.NET Framework) and still works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for testing. It seems that the manifest file actually is created on the disk, but not included into the project automatically.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019 WinForm Projects, it is available under

Project Properties -> Application -> View Windows Settings (button)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022 WinForm Project, it is also available under

Project Properties -> Application:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to obj folder in you app folder, then Debug. In there delete the manifest file and build again.
It worked for me.