# cannot open window service on computer '.' in window application

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows

I develop one window application and I also create one service. I start the service using coding in window application, but I am getting an error like cannot open window service on computer `'.'`

I have used below code.

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("SeoMozScheduleService");

if (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    controller.Start();
}
```

If i right click on Application and click on Run as Administrator than it works fine for me...

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual message, not an error 'like' the message. '.' can sometimes be used to mean the local machine.

Comment: What is the *actual* error message?

Comment: Can you start the service normally?

Comment: I got an Error Like cannot open SeoMozScheduleService on computer '.'

Comment: Yes I can start the Service manually.but why i cant use it in coding.

Comment: Please Help me I am stucking in the Middle...

Comment: If i right click on Application and click on Run as Administrator than it works fine for me...

Comment: So this code runs fine if you run it as admin?

Comment: yes code is fine..but i dont think this is the solution that user has to right click and click on Run as Administrator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to
`c://Program Files/ApplicationFolder/.exe`
Right-click on .exe and go to `Properties` then go `Compatibility Tab` and check true to `Run this Program as an administrator Level`.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote so I'll just comment here and say that elevating permissions is never the right solution because your users might not have admin privileges.

Comment: I run it in  a console as admin, as well the services as admin... and the service did install but it did not start until I set that property. wow, It is a relieve! thanks!

Comment: I agree Jaider. There are a number of server situations where users aren't involved, but automated tasks are being run under a single user. That's part of the beauty of stackoverflow--multiple answers, one of which may work best in your environment.

Comment: Just doing this in a web-api - there's no possibility to run (in my case debug) this as an admin...

Comment: @Tsury in addition to what you say, it is just bad practice to automatically use administrator privileges when lesser privileges are sufficient, right?

Answer (score 18):

To make this automatic every time you open the application you have to [add a manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file) to your solution, then update the `requestedExecutionLevel` node inside the file to look like this:

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

However, changing this setting will result in the system prompting you every time to run the application as administrator if UAC is enabled.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Simply running Visual Studio or the executable as administrator resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using visual studio then close it and re open visual sudio with run it as administrator

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions helped me, because it would help if I actually had ensured I had Administrator access on the target computer first!  I was taking away and giving back Administrator access to my main account using my domain admin account.  When I ran some `ServiceController` code that was checking if a service was running on a remote computer, under the domain admin account, all was fine.  When I did it as my main account, that's when it didn't work - even when running Visual Studio as an Administrator.  Turns out I had been testing without my main account in the local Admin group... d'oh!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this with a scheduled task on a server--checking the "Run with highest privileges" solved it. (The service account has to have admin rights of course for this to work.)

Answer (score 0):

Framework version change in the app.conf to the version which is installed on the system fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The application probably does not need to **require** Administrator permission. The Microsoft Management Console (MMC) (that includes the Services snap-in) does not. The manifest for the MMC has:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel
    level="highestAvailable"
    uiAccess="false"
/>
```

It does not have `level="requireAdministrator"`.

See [c# - How do I create/edit a Manifest file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file) for instructions for adding a manifest to the project.

There are very many articles about the principle of Least Privilege, including the following.

- [Least Privilege](https://www.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/principles/least-privilege)
- [What is principle of least privilege (POLP)? - Definition from WhatIs.com](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/principle-of-least-privilege-POLP)
- [What is the Principle of Least Privilege (POLP)? A Best Practice for Information Security and Compliance \| Digital Guardian](https://digitalguardian.com/blog/what-principle-least-privilege-polp-best-practice-information-security-and-compliance)
- [What Is Least Privilege & Why Do You Need It? \| BeyondTrust](https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/what-is-least-privilege)