# Grant access to non-admin user to start/stop services windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service and a windows application.I want to start and stop this window service from my windows application with arguments.Here is what i have got to start the service

```
  foreach (ServiceController sc in ServiceController.GetServices())
            {
                if (sc.ServiceName == "serviceName")
                {
                    //service is found
                    using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("serviceName"))
                    {
                        string[] args = new string[1];
                        args[0] = "Myargument";
                        if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) 
                        {

                        }
                        else { serviceController.Start(args); }

                }
            }
```

But it gives me **cannot open service on computer '.'** exception.I tried using app.manifest to force run as administrator but still it gives exception.I also tried this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501748/cannot-open-window-service-on-computer-in-window-application) but exception is still there.Does any one know how to grant access to manage services in non-admin user in windows 7 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Windows Service From Application without Admin right(c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379697/start-windows-service-from-application-without-admin-rightc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SetServiceObjectSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the permissions on a service.

I have some code that uses [`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a security descriptor to pass to `SetServiceObjectSecurity`.  Given a security descriptor, you can use `GetSecurityDescriptorDacl` to get the DACL to pass to `SetNamedSecurityInfo`.

The SDDL string I used to create the security descriptor is as follows:

```
wchar_t sddl[] = L"D:"
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)"           // default permissions for local system
  L"(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)"   // default permissions for administrators
  L"(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)"                 // default permissions for authenticated users
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"           // default permissions for power users
  L"(A;;RP;;;IU)"                           // added permission: start service for interactive users
  ;
```

Of course this code will need to be run with elevated permissions.  Typically you would set the permissions at the same time that you install the service.