# stop windows service programmatically c# throwing exception

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service which should stop after some particular date time.
I am able to stop the service programmatically using:

```
try
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(servicename);
        //or
    //ServiceController service = new ServiceController(servicename,computer name);
    service.Stop();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(servicename);
service.Stop();
}
```

**But it throws an exception and does not stop if we remove the finally part.**

**It stopped only after I used the finally statement but obviously the exception persists.**
Exception message:
***Cannot open "Service Name" service on computer '.'***

detailed exception:
***Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'computer name'. This operation might require other privileges.***

I did refer but it does not help also it is not addresses my problem:
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501748/cannot-open-window-service-on-computer-in-window-application)

How can I stop the service programmatically without this exception

Comment: what is the exception you are getting,please attach that too in your question.

Comment: Application that is trying to stop the service has *Admin privilege* ?

Comment: Can you share some code regarding your service implementation? The code you have here looks fine, looks like the service itself is not reacting properly on the stop command.

Comment: @Kurubaran I have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501748/cannot-open-window-service-on-computer-in-window-application
but does not work

Comment: Are you running your program as Administrator?

Comment: surely its a matter of privilages.close application and run it as administrator and check.

Comment: @akhilkumar tried not working

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault yes

Comment: Can you **start** the service in programmatically?

Comment: @Silver , the first message is Cannot **open** "Service Name" or Cannot **stop** "Service Name"?

Comment: @AngusChung cannot open

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the program and choose "Run As Administrator". If you are debugging it, ensure the IDE ( ie Visual Studio I suppose ) is opened with "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I went to the machine in question, and tried to stop the service manually though the interface, and received this pop-up:
[image]

I was able to stop the service by finding the task in Task Manager and ending that task. Not sure what exactly hung up the service but this works if you have access to the machine and task manager.

I was able to start the service and use the `ServiceController` code without any issues after.