# C# console program has to run in Administrator mode always

Tags: c#, console

I have a very basic C# Console App. By clicking the exe I run it. But I want to develop a system where this exe will always run in Administrator mode automatically.
How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7

Comment: I dunno a way, though, I will ask you why you want such a thing. Imagine your program as a virus and the program set to run in admin mode. I cannot   imagine the outcome.

Comment: Add an [Application Manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file) to your project, then set `requestedExecutionLevel ` to `"requireAdministrator"`