# Access Denied Error while creating a file using FileStream in C#

Tags: c#

```
FileStream fs=new FileStream("c:/samplehubdata.xml",
                             FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                             FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                             FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: So add permission to the process that your program is running under. How is this even a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually cannot create a file on Windows in `C:\` without admin priviliges.

Try creating it in your user folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

Write this to get admin access to write on C

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

to your app.manifest
You can create this file if you are not able to see the app.manifest. If you want to know more about the app.manifest you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file)

//edited because he wanted to know how

1. Go to your project and click add
2. Select Visual C# Items
3. Select "Application Manifest File"
4. Call this app.manifest (I guess it is by default)

Comment: I'm writing a C# code so I'm not sure if I will have an app.manifest file.

Comment: I know. Every project has a app.manifest file. Give me a second I will edit my post

Comment: Glad I was able to help you :)
Feel free to leave a green tick ;D