# HttpListener (SelfHost) Nancy Web Server - automate server url registering with admin rights in C#

Tags: c#, owin, nancy, httplistener, netsh

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener` along with `Nancy.Owin` to run a local api server as documented here:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin#katana---httplistener-selfhost

I am trying to automate the this step:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=DOMAIN\username

Here's my test console app:

```
class Program
{
    private static string localApiServerUrl = "http://+:9999";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterLocalApiUrl();

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(localApiServerUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running on {0}", localApiServerUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterLocalApiUrl()
    {
        string args = string.Format(
            @"http add urlacl url={0} user={1}\{2}", 
                localApiServerUrl, 
                Environment.UserDomainName, 
                Environment.UserName);

        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", args)
        {
            Verb = "runas",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        Process.Start(processStartInfo).WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

When this runs, I am not getting prompted run as admin and the **Nancy http server** is failing to launch with this error: **Access Denied**

[image]

This looks like my `netsh` command didn't run to reserve the server address.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: create a manifest file with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Comment: Did you mean to add this into `App.config` entry?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file

Comment: Thanks, that worked, post it as answer - i'll accept it :)

Comment: Better to close as duplicate?