# How to force WPF app for .NET Framework 3.5 use newer L&F?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I'm thinking of making a simple self-contained .NET application with WPF that can run on any modern Windows system without requiring the end-user to download and install .NET Framework *manually*.

As far as I know user just need to click on .exe and wait some time until required libraries are installed.

But applications that were compiled for 3.5 use old L&F on most recent Windows.

Is there any way to make applications look like this:

[image]

and *not* like this (if user *already* has .NET Framework 4+):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [adding a manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file)? make sure you have the `SupportedOS` section.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I did what's in the "Add supported OS" section of [Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801660/3252499), but this had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I came up with simple solution. My assumption was wrong and it appears .NET Framework actually uses L&F of currently running version, not the targeting one.

1. Create `App.config` (Project -> Add -> New Item... -> App configuration (.config))
2. Paste following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <startup>
       <!-- Use 4.0 -->
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
       <!-- Use 2.0 - 3.5 -->
       <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
     </startup>
   </configuration>
   ```

.NET Framework will scan `<supportedRuntime>` until it finds available. List of supported runtimes can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element).