# Unable to find an entry point named 'TaskDialogIndirect DLL ComCtl32

Tags: c#, taskdialog

I am using TaskDialog in one of my projects. It was working quite perfectly after putting in quite  a lot of hard work. But just a moment ago, when I ran my app, suddenly this exception has started to spur up in the same application that was working perfectly fine 5 minutes ago. I am totally flabbergasted.

What could possibly be the reason behind?

Comment: You corrupted your app manifest and now it loads ComCtl32 version 5 that does not have `TaskDialogIndirect`?

Comment: How could that happen? I was tweaking and running my app in Debug mode as usual for testing and improving it, when suddenly in one of these runs, this exception started to appear. Anyway, if this really is the case, how can I fix my manifest file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6050478/11683

Comment: Thanks a lot! How to mark it as answer?

Comment: Click the 'Yes it solves my problem' button.