# C# Run Program as Administrator

Tags: administrator

I want to run my program as administrator.

I compiled the application in Visual Studio already.

Do i can create app.manifest file manually without opening Visual Studio, or place the app.manifest file in my file directory to run it as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file is automatically generated by Visual Studio for applications (that contains app GUID of application and other things similar). And I don't guess if another manifest will be valid for your application.

There's one method to do so, but that also requires Visual Studio referring to [this thread of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file). And remember, the data for the manifest creation should be valid for the application, otherwise it's not guaranteed to be working.