# How can I start the PowerShell with admin rights from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, process, admin-rights

my intention is to start a Powershell process with admin rights to pass it arguments in C#. For that I have written following piece of code

```
public void PassCommand(string command)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

I have read in some other articles thatI just have to add this line `process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";`. But unfortunately it does not work. The Powershell starts without admin rights. Can someone help me to get this solved?

Comment: You must use `UseShellExecute = true`, and you can't redirect input and output, if you want to elevate the powershell. Instead you must elevate your own process first.

Comment: So if I write a console app that calls the powerShell to pass it commands, my console app must be elevated? How can I configure that to start this process always with admin rights?

Comment: Create a shortcut to it I would assume.

Comment: @MarcelMüller [Create an application manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file) and [set the `level` attribute of `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requireAdministrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-securityoverview)