# How can i checkif the user is running a n app as Admin in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a windows app and i use the following to check if running as admin:

```
    public static bool IsAdministrator()
    {
        var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);            
    }

     if (!IsAdministrator())
     {
         AlrtBox.Show("Run as Admin");
     }
```

But if i set a shortcut to the .exe file and set untick the checkbox Run As Administrator, it still seems to run regardless if checked or unchecked.
I guess i am checking if the user is admin on windows(which they are)  , but not if the check box is checked.

I want to check if the app is run as admin , regardless of the user on windows.
How can i do that ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. In what circumstances do you want to return 'IsAdministrator' as true or false? Administrator account? User has admin privileges? RunAs admin account?

Comment: regardless of the user , even if they are admin. I want to make sure that the applicatione (.exe) is run as admin. Ie the checkbox in the Advanced Properties is checked to run as admin ?

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, one way would be try attempt to do something only an admin could - like try to write a harmless value to the HKLM section of the registry?

Comment: Maybe it's better to just attempt the administrative action and handling failure rather than (improperly) checking if it is possible to execute it?

Comment: Your admin test looks right to me. If you don't want to set requireAdministrator in the manifest, you can shell execute "runas" to re-launch your process (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program always needs to run as administrator, you can use an Application.manifest file.

[How do I create/edit a Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file)

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: can i some how do what the manifest file does in c# code ?

Comment: You add the Application.manifest file to your project. On menu, Project => Add New Item => Application Manifest File

Comment: If you only want to check, then you can do something like @stuartd stated in the comments in the previous post, but rather than write a value to the registry, try writing a text file to %SystemRoot%\system32 (ex: C:\Windows\system32). Use exception handling (try-catch). If the write was successful, delete the file.